# Overview of data replication/syncing

Tags: iri-node, syncing

How does the IRI process sync its data between peers? Besides reading the code, is there any information that can explain the process?

Answer (score 13):

*Learning without thought is labor lost; thought without learning is perilous - Confucius*

Jump to the bottom if you want an immediate review. If not, continue along and maybe you might learn a thing or two. As of this writing iri version 1.4.1.2 is the latest release. So the details that follow will be based on this release.

Before we begin, lets start with a visual of the iri process that relates to data replication. We start with the initialization and starting of threads.

[image]

The next image displays a rough workflow of basic external to internal communication. It is no by no means complete. As we progress through learning the inner working of data replication for the iri process, additional information will be presented in a clear concise way.

[image]

## Entry Points

Our discussion begins with the **com.iota.iri.network.UDPReceiver::spawnReceiverThread** and **com.iota.iri.network.replicator.Replicator::replicatorSourcePool** threads. These threads listen on their respective ports defined by the values **UDP_RECEIVER_PORT** and **TCP_RECEIVER_PORT**. Their main role is to accept data, unpack, and send to the main **receiveQueue**.

> **NOTE**: This thread initializes a threadPool the size of 1 or 4*availableProcessors(). The variable for threadPool is called **processor**.  A DatagramPacket object is created called **receivedPacket** with byte buffer and length each 1650.

### com.iota.iri.network.UDPReceiver::spawnReceiverThread

The **spawnReceiverThread** thread, after initialization creates packet counters **processed** and **dropped**.

`int processed = 0, dropped = 0;`

> The packet counters are reset when processed+dropped = **50,000**

This thread will block until data is received on the port defined by **UDP_RECEIVER_PORT**. Packet is size is than validated against expected transaction packet size.

`if (receivingPacket.getLength() == TRANSACTION_PACKET_SIZE) {`

> **NOTE**: The TRANSACTION_PACKET_SIZE equals **1650**

Once validated, a copy of the payload from the received packet and peer address are submitted to the processor pool to be executed by **com.iota.iri.network.Node::preProcessReceivedData** method.

`processor.submit(() -> node.preProcessReceivedData(bytes, address, "udp"));`

After submission, **processed** counter is incremented. If the packet received is invalid, it's rejected and **dropped** counter is incremented. Given the size of the packet **1650**, this is greater than most mtu values. Thus, packet fragmentation will occur. The following line is used to ensure fragmented data is reconstructed into proper transaction packet size.

`receivingPacket.setLength(TRANSACTION_PACKET_SIZE);`

### com.iota.iri.network.replicator.Replicator::replicatorSourcePool

The **replicatorSourcePool** will listen on the **TCP_RECEIVER_PORT** defined port. An ExecutorService thread pool of **32** threads is created prior to entering main loop. The thread will block until data is received. Once data is received, a new **ReplicatorSourceProcessor** is created and submitted to the pool for execution.

**com.iota.iri.network.replicator.ReplicatorSourceProcessor**:

The **ReplicatorSourceProcessor** thread handles the reading and verification of peer packet received. It starts by creating a **data** byte array with a **2000** byte capacity. It then moves into verifiying the remote peer connection to ensure it's an existing neighbor.

`existingNeighbor = false;
List neighbors = node.getNeighbors();
neighbors.stream().filter(n -> n instanceof TCPNeighbor)
  .map(n -> ((TCPNeighbor) n))
  .forEach(n -> {
    String hisAddress = inet_socket_address.getAddress().getHostAddress();
    if (n.getHostAddress().equals(hisAddress)) {
      existingNeighbor = true;
      neighbor = n;
    }
  }
);`

The value of **MAX_PEERS** is tested, including connection from unauthorized neighbors. If either of these occur, a log message is reported and connection is closed. Otherwise, neighbor is added to the **neighbors** array and counter for neighbors is incremented. This is followed by a verification check to ensure an existing neighbor socket connection already exists, if not set one for neighbor object.

`final TCPNeighbor fresh_neighbor = new TCPNeighbor(inet_socket_address,false);
node.getNeighbors().add(fresh_neighbor);
neighbor = fresh_neighbor;
Neighbor.incNumPeers();`

The next section of the code deals with handling/accepting a peer's request. As you'll see in **com.iota.iri.network.ReplicatorSinkProcessor**, an initial **10** byte array is sent which contains the listening service port. It is followed by main payload (**1650** byte length) and it's **16** byte checksum value (prepended with "0" to fill 16 bytes).

> **NOTE:** ReplicatorSinkPool.PORT_BYTES = 10

`offset = 0;
while (((count = stream.read(data, offset, ReplicatorSinkPool.PORT_BYTES - offset)) != -1) && (offset < ReplicatorSinkPool.PORT_BYTES)) {
     offset += count;
}`

Thread exit, if the first 10 bytes of the payload received is not the listener service port or connection is closed. The port value received will be used by the **ReplicatorSinkProcessor** thread to send information back to peer.

The final section of this thread focuses on ensuring proper payload was sent. The full payload in proper order is **10 bytes (peer listener port)**, **1650 bytes (main payload)**, and **16 bytes (checksum)**. The data received is unpacked, checksum validated for main payload, and then submitted to **com.iota.iri.network.Node::preProcessReceivedData** method for processing.

`if (!crcError) {
   node.preProcessReceivedData(data, address, "tcp");
}`

## Summary

The iri process listens on **UDP_RECEIVER_PORT** and **TCP_RECEIVER_PORT** to accept transactions from its peers. Each transaction passes through validation prior to being added to the ledger.

**Syncing**

A node starting up for the first time will attempt to initialize its copy of the tangle by reading everything stored in the database. Once database restore is complete, it will check and see if it's current **latestSolidSubtangleMilestone** matches **latestMilestone**. If they match, random tip selection would ensue unless **transactionsToRequest** queue has increased whereby requests will need to be satisfied by it's peers.

A peer that receives the node's request will look through its own copy of the tangle and if request can be fulfilled, will increment **numberOfRandomTransactionRequests** counter and send transaction to node.

A node that receives a transaction from it's peer that it did not have in it's ledger will process transaction and increment **numberOfNewTransactions**. Since the transaction is considered new, it will also be placed in the **broadcastQueue** to be sent to the node's peers.

During the sync'ing process the **transactionsToRequest** will increase and only decrease as it approaches ledger conformity with its peers. Also through this process, the node will receive transactions that do not match its **latestSolidSubtangleMilestone**, these transactions are simiply queued until they can be processed.

This overview is being published early. Although far from complete, the intent is to help the operator gain an early understanding until additional information can be presented.

Comment: Interesting reading but I'm not sure that this kind of "question" is suitable for this site/Q&A format. It's IMO too broad and looks more like a blog post.

Comment: Understood, I can migrate it to medium when I'm done.

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at this : https://learn.iota.org/blog/how-to-submit-your-own-tutorial

Comment: that's a very good summary! It would be great if you could publish it on medium, too

Comment: Thank you. I plan to. I'll more than likely migrate it in a few weeks.

Comment: When would *in a few weeks* be?

Comment: I have my notes but given things are changing I sorted held off for now. I know in #tanglemath (via slack) it was mentioned more papers will be coming out describing the different facets of iota.