# IOTA OSI layer 4 protocol?

Tags: iota-network

IOTA claims, on their website, to be OSI layer 4 (transport layer). I would like to get information about this. I'm currently working with a MCU and would like to use this protocol. Is there a protocol?

I'm asking because the IRI is using UDP or TCP, but no IOTA protocol. A library would be also great.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference to the statement on the website?

Comment: @TobiMZ This question is really old. Not there anymore. :) 
But here, the old version: https://web.archive.org/web/20180214170308/http://iota.org/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a special IOTA protocol. It just leverages the TCP/UDP protocols for data communication. You may refer to [this question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/623/overview-of-data-replication-syncing?newreg=7e5d71c9ca614f5881548f4d115ab2b4) which is helpful fo me to understand IOTA.